# String from a slice of a byte array

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to make a string from a slice of a byte array, without making a copy of the array? (The array could be quite large, so I want to avoid making multiples of it in memory)

My current code involves using Array.Copy:

```cs
var trimmedArray = new byte[inputArray.Length - bytesToTrim.Length];
Array.Copy(inputArray, bytesToTrim.Length, trimmedArray, 0, trimmedArray.Length);
var outputString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(trimmedArray);
```

Is it possible to get `outputString`, without copying `inputArray` to `trimmedArray`?

Comment: [There's an overload for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring#System_Text_Encoding_GetString_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetString` has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.8) that takes an existing array, a start index and a length, so you should be able to do:

```
var outputString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                       inputArray, 
                       bytesToTrim.Length, 
                       inputArray.Length - bytesToTrim.Length);
```

But note that you don't seem to be looking at the *contents* of `bytesToTrim`, just the length, so it's not clear what the relationship between these two arrays is.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you - exactly what I was looking for. With regards to the relation between `bytesToTrim` and `inputArray` - they have already been compared to decide whether or not to perform this slicing operation.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET Core 2.1+ (or using the [System.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/) NuGet package with .NET Framework 4.5+) you could convert the array to a `Span<byte>` and slice it:

```
var outputString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inputArray.AsSpan().Slice(length));
```

Please refer to Stephen Toub's [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/january/csharp-all-about-span-exploring-a-new-net-mainstay) for more information about the `Span<T>` type.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use the Span class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.slice?view=netcore-3.1

It will help you to avoid any allocation.